# How to use var from another file with PHP

Tags: php, sql, function, class, variables

I am trying to use var $db in config.php file, the $db var is a mysqli class ready
I use this line in my config file

```
$db = new MysqliDb ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
```

and use it inside of my functions.php file like this

```
    public function save_ship($user = '')
{
    global $db;
```

and then to use the var i use:

```
array(
            'ship_heder' => $this->$db->escape($arr[$i]['ship_heder']),
            'ship_num' => $this->$db->escape($arr[$i]['ship_num']),
            'ship_type' => $this->$db->escape($arr[$i]['ship_type']),
            'ship_isuf_cust_no' => $this->$db->escape($arr[$i]['ship_isuf_cust_no']),
            'ship_address' => $this->$db->escape($arr[$i]['ship_address']),
            'phone_to_call' => $this->$db->escape($arr[$i]['phone_to_call']),
            'ship_line' => $this->$db->escape($arr[$i]['ship_lines']['0']['ship_line']),
            'date_time' => $date->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'),
            'uid' => $user,
        );
```

and it gives me error.. any idea how to solve?
thanks!

Comment: Did you include/require config.php in your functions.php file?

Comment: `$this->$db` makes no sense. Where did the `$this` come from? You are using a global variable not an object property.

Comment: I think you need to study objects a bit more carefully. And avoid using globals wherever you can, it's almost always an antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your config file to functions.php by just adding this line at the top of your code:

include_once('config.php');

Comment: That's half the answer